Laser frame to base frame python
Good evening people, First of all I would like to apologize for my limited understanding in ROS and Python, as I have been experimenting for almost 3 months now. Can any one please explain how can I transform laser point data into base frame data using python and ros2 with explanation? I am doing some projects with kelo robot?

Here are the steps you need to take:

Use basic geometry to convert the LaserScan data from polar coordinates (range, angle) to cartesian coordinates (x,y,0) in the LaserScan frame. Create a PointStamped object for each point, setting z=0. Call this p.
Use lookup_transform() to get the transformation info from laserscan_frame to base_frame. You only need to do this once.
For each p, use the helper function tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point() to convert a point into the base_frame.

Here is a ros1 example using the similar do_transform_pose() function. The ros2 code should be nearly identical.
